# Metadata API: where is the Connected App / OAuth policies / Permitted Users setting?

Tags: metadata-api, oauth

Salesforce.com setup screen has, in "Administer" section -> "Manage Apps" menu -> "Connected Apps" -> edit app page, a setting called "Permitted Users". This setting allows the portal administrator to decide if users can be allowed to approve the connected app themselves or to auto-approve the app for any profile admin wishes.

My problem is: when doing a metadata download through the Force.com Migration Tool, I can't find this setting. Am I missing something, or is this setting cannot be accessed with the Metadata API?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, it's not supported by the Metadata API. What's weird, however, is that there's no mention of permissions under [ConnectedApp](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_connectedapp.htm), which suggests that it is not supported, but it's *also* not mentioned under [Unsupported Metadata Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm), which mildly suggests that it *is* supported. That said, since it can't be found in either place, and given the fact that I can't seem to find it in the metadata either, suggests that it's not supported. You may want to open a case with support to confirm that it's not supported, since we probably need to submit feedback to the documentation team to have the manual updated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I'll try to contact the Salesforce support. I'll keep this question opened for a while - I'll accept your answer as soon as support gets.back to me.

Comment: @DmitriyKhudorozhkov Sure thing. In fact, I'd love to be wrong, because it seems awfully inconvenient to not have this available by way of the API.

Comment: absolutely. I've just stumbled upon this very situation :/

Comment: I don't really believe my eyes as this is a loong time coming, but looks like Summer '20 is making `oauthPolicy` and `sessionPolicy` visible and hopefully editable: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_api_meta.htm

Comment: Facing this exact situation, but seems the metadata APIs still do not support it.